# Passing data from controller to middleware laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, controller, laravel-middleware

I have a problem when I want to pass data to the view via the middleware to count the number of users. when not using middleware, variable from controller get to the view.

my HomeController.php

```
 public function index()
    {
        $count = User::count();
        return view('admin.Dashboard', compact($count);
    }
```

my Middleware

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role == 'admin') {
            return response()->view('admin.Dashboard');
        } else {
            return response()->view('member.dashboard');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

the `$count` variable if using middleware in route not passed to the view

my web.php

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('verified', 'cekrole')->name('home');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your middleware you are returning response (a view), so

```php
return $next($request);
```

will never be executed, so neither will your controller.

User call /dashboard > Your middleware is called > if it's an admin you are returning admin.Dashboard, else member.dashboard.

But you never execute code in your Controller.

As a quick fix you could replace your Middleware by :

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user() && $request->user()->role == 'admin') {
            $count = User::count();
            return view('admin.Dashboard', compact('count'));
        } 
        return response()->view('member.dashboard');

    }
```

or make those test (admin/not admin) in your controller

Comment: You probably meant `compact('count')`.